# Problems setting DynamoDB table name from application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

I have seen a reply somewhere on StackOverflow that you can set a table name dynamically like this:

```kotlin
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "\${dynamodb.mentions}")
data class MentionItem (
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "mentioned_user")
    var mentionedUserId: String = "",

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "message_id")
    var messageId: String = "",

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "mentioned_tag")
    var mentionedTag: String? = null

)
```

Need to add that when I tried to access table name in another class like this, spring picks up the value from my properties file:

```
    @Value("\${dynamodb.mentions}")
    lateinit var mentionsTableName: String
```

Spring picks up the value from the properties file, but the same doesn't work from the `DynamoDBTable` annotation.

**Is there a way to set a table name from the `application.properties` file**

Answer (score 1):

So far I have only found this way to do it and it is to use mapperConfig:

```
DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder().withTableNameOverride(TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement(yourTableName)).build()
```

In the service where I do the post to Dynamo:

```kotlin
@Service
class MessageService() {
    @Value("\${dynamodb.mentions}")
    lateinit var mentionsTableName: String

  fun postMentions(messageId: String, mentionedEmployeeId: String, mentionedTag: String) {
        val mapper = DynamoDBMapper(dynamoConfiguration.amazonDynamoDB())
        val mapperConfig =
            DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder().withTableNameOverride(TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement(mentionsTableName))
                .build()
        mapper.save(
                MentionDevItem(
                    mentionedUserId = it.mentionedEmployeeId,
                    messageId = messageId,
                    mentionedTag = it.mentionedTag,
                ),
                mapperConfig,
            )
    }


}
```